# Workaround/Bypass on 3900 length limit on formula field

Tags: workflow, formula

I have a requirement where in need to build a formula for country code and Product code. Formula which i have built has a length of 44000 char and i see the length allowed on formula field are 3900. Can someone suggest if there is any other workaround to get this done.

Thanks!!

Comment: You may have to write a trigger to update the field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rahul. Apart from customization can this be achieved through general configuration?

Comment: post your formula here and we can try to optimize it

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass that limit to have a limit of `5000` ([compiled size](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_field_limits.htm&type=0)) chars, by externalizing all long strings to custom labels

*Example where you can do that* :

Without custom label  : `CONTAINS('Value1,Value2,...ValueN',valueToCheck)`

With custom label  : `CONTAINS($Label.myCustomLabel,valueToCheck)`

If you can't achieve that with a custom label, then you'll need to create a new formula field to split your formula into two (<3900), and have the 5000 compiled limit size

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the functionality using below approach : -

1. Create Long Text Area If the output of the formula ix Text based otherwise create field as per your requirement.
2. Need to incorporate trigger to calculate formula which you are trying in the formula field.

OR

you can write a workflow to update the field providing the same logic in field update. This will work only if your field is not of type Checkbox, Picklist etc.

Yes you can go for workflow, but the character limit is 5000.So based on your requirement you need to select the approach.